# Django - join list of objects in templates on specific attribute

Tags: django

Is it possible to join a list of model objects (using the join template tag), except not to join the objects' unicode values, but rather a certain field for each?

e.g.
{{ objects.field|join", " }} should return "object1.field, object2.field, ..."
where objects is a list of model instances.

I know that iteration is an option, but am wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a custom templatetag.

```
@register.filter
def join_by_attr(the_list, attr_name, separator=', '):
    return separator.join(unicode(getattr(i, attr_name)) for i in the_list)
```